# How to execute a lua script from mysql-proxy

Tags: mysql, lua, mysql-proxy

I am trying to execute a lua script from mysql proxy.
I wrote a script called login.lua .I installed mysql-proxy successfully.I tried to invoke the command 
`mysql-proxy --proxy-lua-script=/path/to/login.lua` 
And then i started the mysql client and entered password to login.

I am expecting mysql client to invoke mysql proxy and hence expecting login.lua to get executed on the command-line. Is this an expected behaviour? If so,am i missing any configuration that is responsible for the client to invoke the proxy ??

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made sure that the MySQL client connects to the correct host and port? It should be the one of the proxy and not the one of the MySQL server. The port is by default 4040.

Comment: Right. The default port is something else i guess. I got it working but forgot to post an answer.Thanks anyway!